# Ubuntu cannot find or detect new wired network adapter

Tags: ubuntu, networking

I want to use two ethernet cards on my machine. So I've physically inserted the new ethernet card in to my machine. However when enter the `ifconfig -a` command Ubuntu cannot find or detect the new device. So I have tried to bring up the new device in the usual manner and I received the error:

```
ifconfig eth1 up
eth1: error fetching interface information: Device not found
```

This is when i enter `ifconfig -a` command

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:17:31:53:b7:9c  
  UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
  RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
  TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
  collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
  RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
  Interrupt:17 Memory:cffe0000-d0000000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
  inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
  inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
  UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
  RX packets:2249 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
  TX packets:2249 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
  collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
  RX bytes:362973 (362.9 KB)  TX bytes:362973 (362.9 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 64:70:02:25:6d:e4  
  inet addr:192.168.150.5  Bcast:192.168.150.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
  inet6 addr: fe80::6670:2ff:fe25:6de4/64 Scope:Link
  UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
  RX packets:14219 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
  TX packets:18637 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
  collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
  RX bytes:8525631 (8.5 MB)  TX bytes:3548272 (3.5 MB)
```

Ubuntu cannot find/or detect the newly installed device.

I'm using a `Silan SC92031 PCI Fast Ethernet Adapter`. I've checked for a module that correspond to it and I found `sc92031.ko'. I tried to load that module using modprobe command

```
 `modprobe -v sc92031`
```

Afterwards I checked whether that module had been successfully loaded using this command:

```
#cat /proc/modules |grep sc92031
 sc92031 18108 0 - Live 0xf8436000
```

I rebooted my machine. After booting Ubuntu still cannot find or detect the new network adapter. It appears that the module has disappeared or has been unloaded automatically.

```
lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 82945G/GZ/P/PL Memory Controller Hub  (rev 02)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 82945G/GZ Integrated    Graphics     Controller (rev 02)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 01)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family PCI Express Port 1 (rev 01)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family PCI Express Port 2 (rev 01)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 01)
00:1d.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 01)
00:1d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 01)
00:1d.3 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 01)
00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB2 EHCI Controller (rev 01)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev e1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82801GB/GR (ICH7 Family) LPC Interface  Bridge (rev 01)
00:1f.1 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801G (ICH7 Family) IDE Controller (rev 01)
00:1f.2 IDE interface: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family SATA Controller [IDE  mode] (rev 01)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family SMBus Controller (rev 01)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82573L
```

Does anyone have any ideas what I can do next to diagnose this issue?

Comment: If you `modrpobe` a module, it will not be persistent accross reboots. After the `modprobe` try restarting networking (whithout a reboot).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`lspci` doesn't show your network adapter. That means it isn't connected to the PCI bus. All PCI peripherals appear in the `lspci` output, regardless of whether you have a driver for them: it's a PCI feature. The text descriptions (like “Intel Corporation 82573L”) are from a database, but the controller would at least appear as “Ethernet controller: Device 1904:2031” or some such. So there's a hardware problem, either your adapter doesn't work, or the PCI slot doesn't work, or there's a bad connection or an incompatibility or something.

Once you solve the hardware problem, the right driver should be loaded automatically and the interface will appear in `ifconfig -a`. If the driver isn't loaded automatically but the hardware is present, that would mean that the driver doesn't recognize your hardware.

Answer (score 3):

Most likely the device isn't listed in /etc/network/interfaces

try adding
`iface eth1 inet dhcp`
to that file